# Unity Xcode build failed with error: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-mobile-ads, applovin

I have build failed Unity project in Xcode with error: "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". I try to double click on it to get more information, but all i have is still this error.

About my Unity Project:
I use GoogleMobileAds package (8.5.0), and Applovin has Google Admob. When build in Unity, i have error:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK":
In Podfile:
AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter (= 10.5.0.1) was resolved to 10.5.0.1, which depends on
Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 10.5.0)

```
Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 10.9)
```

Specs satisfying the `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 10.9), Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 10.5.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I try to upgrade Google Admob to newest version to build but this still has this error, the only difference is version of Google Admob in error.
Then i fixed it by change the version of Google Admob in dependencies file to ios 10.9.0.1 (MaxSdk/Mediation/Google/Editor/Dependencies.xml). Then i build success and continue to Xcode build.

Unity version: 2020.3.38f
macOS: Sonoma 14.1.1
Cocoapods: 1.15.2

In Xcode, I both enabled Bitcode and disable it, delete input in shell at build phase, create header file, add flag -lxml2 into other Linker flag, but it still have this error. I also  try to update cocoapod to newest version.
What can i do now to fix this error in XCode?
Thanks!!!

Comment: To make others do further action, you'd better add up your original generated Xcode Project's Podfile and 'pod install' running result in the terminal.